# Cannot start XAMPP MySQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

Please help..

I have website running on XAMPP Apache and MySQL (v3.1.0) with Windows Server 2003, it works fine for almost 5 year. I often restart the MySQL service. But today when I stopped the MySQL service and tried to start, it nothing happen, MySQL service still stopped.

When I saw the log, it seems failed to initialize buffer pool. Below snippet of the log

`171214 10:13:06 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
171214 10:13:06 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
171214 10:13:06 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
171214 10:13:06 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
171214 10:13:06 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 171214 10:14:28 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
171214 10:14:28 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
171214 10:14:28 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
171214 10:14:28 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
171214 10:14:28 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 171214 10:17:32 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
171214 10:17:32 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
171214 10:17:32 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
171214 10:17:32 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
171214 10:17:32 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 171214 10:23:24 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.`

Below are snippet log for success mysql startup

`171213 13:39:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
171213 13:39:47 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
171213 13:39:47 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
171213 13:39:47 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
171213 13:39:47 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G
171213 13:39:48 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
171213 13:39:48 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
171213 13:39:49  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
171213 13:39:50 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 197337651912
171213 13:39:50 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
171213 13:39:50 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
171213 13:39:50 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
171213 13:39:50 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
171213 13:39:50 [Note] d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.27-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

(from Comment)

```
[mysqld] 
port    = 3306 
socket  = /tmp/mysql.sock 
skip-external-locking 
key_buffer_size = 256M 
max_allowed_packet = 1M 
table_open_cache = 64 
sort_buffer_size = 512K 
net_buffer_length = 8K 
read_buffer_size = 256K 
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K 
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M 
max_connections = 500 
key_buffer = 256M 
table_cache = 256M 
slow-query-log=1 
slow-query-log-file=D:\TABLETEMP\my.slow.log 
long_query_time=1 
log_error="mysql_error.log"
```

Comment: It's not a space issue? How's your disk? Do you have backups? I hope so, because a 5 year run without corruption/problems with MySQL on Windows is good going!

Comment: I strictly maintaned the disk and the memory usage. Disk free space are 16.8 GB free of 132 GB. The size of mysql folder are 3.5 GB. Are you think I must free more disk space? For backup, unfortunately I don't backup the database regularly, last backup is last year.

Answer (score 1):

171214 is terribly small.  Change `my.cnf` to set it to about 70% of available RAM.  Example, for a 16GB system, use 11G.  If that antique server is only 2GB, use 500M.

`table_cache = 256M` is terribly big -- the units is tables, not bytes.  Furthermore, in newer versions, the name is `table_open_cache`, so:

```
table_open_cache = 500
```

(How did the date get there?  171214 = Dec 14, 2017)

Or is the field left blank??

(From Comment, plus annotations)

```
 [mysqld]
 port   = 3306
 socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
 skip-external-locking
 key_buffer_size = 256M     -- Change to 50M
 max_allowed_packet = 1M
 table_open_cache = 64      -- let's change to 200
 sort_buffer_size = 512K
 net_buffer_length = 8K
 read_buffer_size = 256K
 read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
 myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
 max_connections = 500    -- 100, until you have a good reason for more
 key_buffer = 256M      -- Remove, old spelling
 table_cache = 256M     -- Remove; this is an old spelling
 slow-query-log=1
 slow-query-log-file=D:\TABLETEMP\my.slow.log
 long_query_time=1       -- good
 log_error="mysql_error.log" 

 innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1000M  -- compromise between 'safe' and 'useful'
```

Comment: Do you mean parameter this paramater in my.ini "innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G". My server RAM are 4 GB.

Comment: @cyde007 - is that in the `[mysqld]` section?  It does not seem to be taking effect.

Comment: It is in folder mysql/bin. I'm using Windows and cannot found mysqld

Comment: @cyde007 - Look at the text in the my.ini (or my.cnf) file.  You should see a text line with nothing but `[mysqld]`.  The setting must come after that, but before the next `[...]` line.

Comment: do you mean this?[mysqld]
port  = 3306
socket  = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
max_connections = 500
key_buffer = 256M
table_cache = 256M
slow-query-log=1
slow-query-log-file=D:\TABLETEMP\my.slow.log
long_query_time=1
log_error="mysql_error.log"

Comment: @cyde007 - that's where to add it.  And use `1500M`.

Comment: Do you mean like this "innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1500M"?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: I have change innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1500M and table_cache = 500. But still cannot start MySQL

Comment: @cyde007 - I added 6 recommended changes to my Answer.